# Set state in React component from props and update when props change?

Tags: reactjs

My React component sets a state property called userInGroup based on props.

```
    this.state = {
        userInGroup: this.props.user
            ? this.props.user.groups.includes(props.group._id)
            : false,
    };
```

This works but does not update when the props change and the value of userInGroup should also change, until I refresh the page. How can I make this update reactively?

Maybe I could use componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate but then Id be repeating the logic used by userInGroup. Is this repetition inevitable?

Comment: Yes. You could write a function to calculate it though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you need to make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` along with `constructor/componentDidMount`, when you want to update state when props change since `constructor/componentDidMount` are called only once when the component mounts, and `componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props or the Parent component updates

You could write a function that contains the logic

```
this.state = {
        userInGroup: this.getUserStatus();
    };

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.user !== this.props.user) {
        this.setState({userInGroup: this.getUserStatus(nextProps)})
    }
}
getUserStatus = (newProps) => {
    const data = newProps || this.props
    return data.user
            ? data.user.groups.includes(data.group._id)
            : false
}
```

Comment: Today, (or after React 16, I think), [`componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) replaces the now deprecated [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger, yes you are right, However, Its actually getDerivedStateFromProps(memoization) that is a fit here. I will update my answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  Please, update the answer as you promised. Show the `getDerivedStateFromProps` approach

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). The other methods are now deprecated and deemed unsafe.

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for implementing a  component that compares its previous and next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  return {
    userInGroup: props.user
      ? props.user.groups.includes(props.group._id)
      : false,
  }
}
```