# Which component life cycle method to use to set the state based on the prop value changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

which component method can we use to set the state based the prop value changes?  i know we can use componentWillRecieveProps but it is going to be deprecated so which can we use as a alternative to componentWillRecieveProps. also please post a simple code example if possible

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState),you can use this alternative of componentWillreceiveProps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set state in React component from props and update when props change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880880/set-state-in-react-component-from-props-and-update-when-props-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class components you can now use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)`

A example from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#alternative-1-reset-uncontrolled-component-with-an-id-prop):

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Any time the current user changes,
    // Reset any parts of state that are tied to that user.
    // In this simple example, that's just the email.
    if (props.userID !== state.prevPropsUserID) {
      return {
        prevPropsUserID: props.userID,
        email: props.defaultEmail
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `componentDidUpdate` method

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but when changing the state based on prop changes, maybe `shouldComponentUpdate` would be a better choice, that way you could skip the prop rerender and only use the statechange rerender.

Comment: Good point, I didn't read OPs question carefully enough and didn't see that he wanted to change the state based on prop changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
 if (nextProps.total !== prevState.total) {
   //your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> getDerivedStateFromProps

It was introduced in react 16.3 to replace :

> componentWillReceiveProps

which will be deprecated in react 17 and now become

> UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
if(nextProps.someValue!==prevState.someValue){
return { someState: nextProps.someValue};
} else return null;
}
```

This lifecycle method take the previous and the next props as an input and return the derived state.
This method is static so you cant use `this` inside.

For further information read [Replacing ‘componentWillReceiveProps’ with ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’](http://%E2%80%9CReplacing%20%E2%80%98componentWillReceiveProps%E2%80%99%20with%20%E2%80%98getDerivedStateFromProps%E2%80%99%E2%80%9D%20by%20Amanshu%20Kataria%20https://link.medium.com/r7Bg2Ba74Z)